# TrustFailure error with a WebClient on OVH server in Xamarin

Tags: php, xamarin, ssl-certificate, webclient, ovh

I have 3 environments, 1 for dev, 1 for tests, and 1 for production.

The 3 run the same code, but dev and test are on our web server (Gandi), and prod on client web server (OVH).

The server is used for some web services, and was running great for months. The issue appeared on the 26 of September.

I am using a WebClient object in Xamarin to call the web services.

No issue on dev and test, but "Error : TrustFailure (Authentication failed, see inner exception)" on prod.

I made a lot of research, and it seam to be an SSL certificate issue. On my OVH panel, the SSL certificate are enabled and the web site is working great with HTTPS.

I am a newbie with network / server issues, and running out of idea. My htaccess seam to be ok.

Thanks

Comment: "see inner exception" - what does the InnerException show?

Comment: I don't really know, this error message already come from an Exception so, I didn't find yet where is the "inner exeption"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.innerexception?view=net-5.0

Comment: You just learned me something, didn't knew for the Exception.InnerException ! Thanks

But Exception.InnerException has the same message. 

But just found at StackTrace : "  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessAuthentication (System.Boolean runSynchronou…"

I will investigate on this, thanks

Comment: I now got this error : Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED\n at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132

Maybe I will find something with this

Comment: Are you using a Let's Encrypt Cert?

Comment: I don't know what is it so I think not

EDIT : OVH automatically put let's encrypt cert ! My bad

Comment: So, for now, I found something that disable the ssl authentication from my xamarin app. The app can work again for the customer. Also, I created a OVH support ticket, maybe they will be able to help me on this. I will update here when I will have more information